# Как перевести код из Angular приложения, написанный на TypeScript, в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, angular2, typescript, angular4

Есть сайт, написанный с помощью Angular на TypeScript. Этот сайт - тестовое задание. Итог нужно представить в виде JS кода, а не TS. Т.к. с помощью TS я создал определенную структуру, то возник вопрос: как перевести TS в JS?
Я знаю про ng-build в angular-cli, но он минимизирует код, делает его непонятным для разбора. Мне же важно сохранить структуру.
Ещё я где-то слышал про "настроить сборку", но так и не понял, что это.
Помогите советом!

Comment: Можно отдельно запустить компилятор ts. Он певедет вам ts на js. Вот небольшой туториал https://adminhacks.com/typescript-compile.html. Правда не уверен, что ангуляр приложение будет после этого работать, т.к. angular-cli делает еще кучу вещей)